# Including CSS and JavaScript as Web Forms User Controls and making it as fast as possible

Tags: asp.net

I would like to include CSS and JavaScript directly in ASP.Net Web Form and the first thing that I am using now is Web Forms User Control like this:

```
<head runat="server">
  <uc1:bootstrap_css runat="server" id="bootstrap_css" />
  <uc1:bootstrap_icons_css runat="server" id="bootstrap_icons_css" />
  <uc1:cookieconsent_min_css runat="server" ID="cookieconsent_min_css" />
  <uc1:normalize_css runat="server" ID="normalize_css" />
  <uc1:splide_css runat="server" ID="splide_css" />
</head>
```

And uc1:bootstrap_css looks something like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" 
  AutoEventWireup="false"
  Debug="false"  
  EnableTheming="false" 
  EnableViewState="false" 
  ValidateRequestMode="Disabled" 
  ViewStateMode="Disabled" 
  WarningLevel="0" 
  Strict="false" 
  Inherits="eee.css.bootstrap_css" %>
<style>
  @charset "UTF-8";/*!
 * Bootstrap v5.0.0-beta2 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2021 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2021 Twitter, Inc.
....
</style>
```

Now I see that User Control has some properties like CompilationMode, AutoEventWireup, etc. How to set those properties so it will reduce server processing to the minimum?